# pyspark localiterator listener has stopped

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am using pyspark

I use this code:

```
a = rdd.map(lambda x: function).toLocalIterator()
from collections import Counter
c = sum(a,Counter())
```

and get the following error

> ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping
>   event
>
> > SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@1ada509b)
>
> WARN Utils: Suppressing exception in finally: Connection reset
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)   at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>     at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)    at
>   java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:707)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1346)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2.run(PythonRDD.scala:706)
>     Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)        at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)       at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
>         at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
>         at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>         at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
>         at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
>         ... 3 more

when I use this code instead, it gets me the right result with no error

```
c = Counter()
for i,pair in a:
    c+=Counter(pair)
```

I tried to play with the partitions in the rdd map.

Nothing works.

The two code sections should work in the same way, what is the difference? why would the first not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the lack of memory on the driver, i solved it using

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "3G")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

before staring the spark context